# Show/hide next input field based on dropdown selection

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue.js. I want to know how to show next input field based on previous dropdown menu selection. I have checked other forums and tried to implement but that didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<select v-model="receive_method" id="">
                                          <option value="cheque">Cheque</option>
                                          <option value="eftn">EFTN</option>
                                          <option value="cash">CASH</option>
                                      </select>
                                      <div v-if="receive_method === 'Cheque' ">
                                        <input type="integer" v-model="cheque_number" placeholder="Cheque Number">
                                      </div>
```

If I select cheque option from the dropdown list the next input field will appear else it will remain hidden.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the `value` of the `option`s element.

If `value="cheque"` is lowercase, `v-if="receive_method === 'cheque'"` should too.

[This works](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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):

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const receive_method = ref()
const cheque_number = ref()
</script>

<template>
  <select v-model="receive_method" id="">
    <option value="cheque">Cheque</option>
    <option value="eftn">EFTN</option>
    <option value="cash">CASH</option>
  </select>
  <div v-if="receive_method === 'cheque'">
    <input type="integer" v-model="cheque_number" placeholder="Cheque Number">
  </div>
</template>
```

If  using Options API

```html
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        receive_method: undefined,
        cheque_number: undefined
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Where should I include the codes inside script tag ? Is this part mandatory ?

Comment: These are just reactive variables. See my edit, if you are using Options API.

Comment: @TanjibRubyat - I would advise reading over the Vue JS Docs on Data Properties and Methods linked here to understand what the code within the script tag thats provided in the answer is doing as this will help your understanding - https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html

Comment: Ok..............